# how to wrap a component that can wrap other components in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

say I have a component that can have children components like this

```
<Component>
    <Child/>
    <Child/>
</Component>
```

turns out I did not create this component, it comes from an external dependency, but I would like to use this component in various places passing the same props, for that I thought of a ParentComponent to wrap Component up. I have done that before and it worked as long as the component being wrapped does not surround other components like this one. How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: See [`Higher-Order Components(HOC)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Comment: it teaches how to wrap a component, but in the examples it returns a simple component. I want to wrap a component that surrounds others. a component that is going to be used with opening and closing tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use React.Fragment to wrap the component but it will not be appear in dom

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to pass down the `children` props, so you can create the following element

```
const Wrapper = ({children}) => (
  <Component>
    <Child/>
    <Child/>
    {children}
  </Component>
)
```

and then use it as

```
<Wrapper>
  <span>hi</span>
</Wrapper>
```

the final rendered tree will be

```
<Component>
  <Child/>
  <Child/>
  <span>hi</span>
</Component>
```